# Copy files from a local to remote folder with scp and script throws "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scp

**Description**

I want to copy all files ending on .jpg from my local machine to the remote machine with scp.
For this i have a small "script". It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


xfce4-terminal -e "scp -r -v /path/to/local/folder/*.jpg <user>@<IP>:/var/path/to/remote/folder/" --hold
```

**Problem**

When i open a terminal and enter `scp -r -v /path/to/local/folder/*.jpg <user>@<IP>:/var/path/to/remote/directory/` it works.
So SSH is working correct.

When i start the script it doesnt.
The script works, when i copy the whole local folder. It then looks like this (simply the `*.jpg` is removed):

```
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-terminal -e "scp -r -v /path/to/local/folder/ <user>@<IP>:/var/path/to/remote/folder/" --hold
```

But then i have the local folder inside the remote folder, where i only want to have the files.

I dont know, if it is important but currently i use a computer with Linux Mint 19.3, xfce terminal and zshell.

**Question**

So how do i run a script correctly that copys files from a local folder to remote folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the shell who expands the wildcard, but when you run `-e` in xfce4-terminal, it runs the command without letting the shell parse it. You can run a shell to run the command, though:

```
xfce4-terminal -e "bash -c 'scp -r -v /path/to/local/folder/*.jpg user@ip:/var/path/to/remote'" --hold
```

Are you sure you need the `-r`? Directories are usually not named `.jpg`.

Comment: If "folder" contains subfolders containing files other than jpg images and you only want to copy the images, rsync is a better tool for this task

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That worked. No, i didn't need the `-r`. Removed it.
@KyleBanerjee why is rsync better?

Comment: rsync would skip the files already present in the target, reducing the volume of data to transfer.

Comment: Also, rsync gives you much more control over which files are and aren't transferred -- wasn't quite clear how much flexibility you needed from your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications :)